# scalars comparison in dplyr filter

Tags: r, dplyr

In the following reproducible example I want to filter the rows in df where an expression of the variables gives a specific result. Rows 1 and 3 meet the requirements and should be returned. However my first attempt was not correct since I used `==` for comparing scalars.

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,8,3,7,4,5,6,2,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,6,4,3,5,8,1,7,2),ncol=9,byrow=T))

df %>%
    filter(X1+13*X2/X3+X4+12*X5-X6-11+X7*X8/X9-10==66)

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
1  9  6  4  3  5  8  1  7  2
```

The I tried to correct my error using the isTRUE(all.equal(...)) approach but, to my surprise I got no results at all.

```
df %>%
    filter(isTRUE(all.equal(X1+13*X2/X3+X4+12*X5-X6-11+X7*X8/X9-10,66))) 

[1] X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

How should I perform this comparison?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`all.equal` is not vectorized - why not

```
df %>% 
    filter(abs(X1+13*X2/X3+X4+12*X5-X6-11+X7*X8/X9-10 - 66) < 1e-8)
```

Answer (score 1):

`isTRUE` returns a length-one logical vector and so your second statement is equivalent to

```
df %>% filter(FALSE)
```

To get your desired result, you probably have to do some extra work. One possibility is to use mutate to calculate if your condition is satisfied and then to filter.

```
df %>% 
  # calculate condition
  mutate(value = X1+13*X2/X3+X4+12*X5-X6-11+X7*X8/X9-10, 
         cond = sapply(value, function(x) isTRUE(all.equal(x, 66)))) %>%
  # filter
  filter(cond) %>%
  # remove unnecessary values
  mutate(value = NULL, cond = NULL)
##   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
## 1  1  8  3  7  4  5  6  2  9
## 2  9  6  4  3  5  8  1  7  2
```

Comment: You are correct! But the code now gets very slow. Try using this dataframe:  library(gtools); df <- tbl_df(data.frame(permutations(9,9))). Compare your solution with the one provided by konvas.